# Navigate to a flutter widget from a flame game without losing the game state

Tags: flutter, flame

My flame game concept is that a player moves, and when the player collides with a star object, a pop up flutter window contains a question shall appear, and when the user closes it, the game state and player position will be restored.How can I do so?

I tried Navigator.push but it doesn't work, it says that no context available :(

Also I tried a different way, which is the overlay, but the Star class cannot access the overlays property, I wrote a method in the main game class "PlayerWithBG" but calling it throws an exception...

This is the code inside Star class

```
import 'package:flame/collisions.dart';
import 'package:flame/components.dart';
import 'package:flame/sprite.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:khalooq/Game/PlayerWithBG.dart';
import '../Questions/firstLevelQuestions.dart';
import 'helpers/directions.dart';

class Star extends SpriteAnimationComponent
    with HasGameRef, CollisionCallbacks {
  Star(Vector2 position)
      : super(size: Vector2.all(50), position: position, anchor: Anchor.center);

  final gameObject = PlayerWithBG();

  late final SpriteAnimation _rotateAnimation;
  final double _animationSpeed = .3;
  Direction direction = Direction.right;

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    super.onLoad();
    await _loadAnimations().then((_) => {animation = _rotateAnimation});
    add(CircleHitbox());
  }

  Future<void> _loadAnimations() async {
    final spriteSheet = SpriteSheet.fromColumnsAndRows(
        image: await gameRef.images.load('stars1.png'), columns: 10, rows: 1);

    _rotateAnimation = spriteSheet.createAnimation(
        row: 0, stepTime: _animationSpeed, from: 0, to: 4);
  }

  @override
  void onCollision(Set<Vector2> intersectionPoints, PositionComponent other) {
    super.onCollision(intersectionPoints, other);
    // gameObject.showQuestion();
    // calling the showQuestion() method throws an exception in the method
    /*
     * Exception has occurred.
      _AssertionError ('package:flame/src/game/overlay_manager.dart': Failed assertion: line 51 pos 7: '_builders.containsKey(name)': Trying to add an unknown overlay "Question")
     */

    removeFromParent();
    //This is what I want to do--------------------------------------------------
    // Navigator.push(
    //     context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => firstLevelQuestion()));
  }
}
```

And this is the code inside the main game class "PlayerWithBG"

```
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flame/game.dart';
import 'package:flame/input.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'Player.dart';
import 'GameBG.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'Star.dart';
import 'helpers/directions.dart';

class PlayerWithBG extends FlameGame
    with KeyboardEvents, HasCollisionDetection, TapDetector {
  Player _player = Player();
  GameBG _gameBG = GameBG();

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    super.onLoad();
    await add(_gameBG);
    double bgWidth = _gameBG.size.x;
    double bghight = _gameBG.size.y;
    await add(_player);
    _player.position = Vector2(bgWidth * 0.05, bghight * 0.95);
    camera.followComponent(_player,
        worldBounds: Rect.fromLTRB(0, 0, _gameBG.size.x, _gameBG.size.y));
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //Stars are the elements that should open the question when the player collides with them
    add(Star(Vector2(bgWidth * 0.10, bghight * 0.95)));
    add(Star(Vector2(bgWidth * 0.30, bghight * 0.95)));
  }

  void showQuestion() {
    if (overlays.isActive('Question')) {
      overlays.remove('Question');
      resumeEngine();
    } else {
      overlays.add('Question');
      pauseEngine();
    }
  }

  onArrowKeyChanged(Direction direction) {
    _player.direction = direction;
  }
}
```

And here where I call the game widget with a temp overlay container

```
          GameWidget(
            game: game..paused = false,
            //here is the overlayer to render the question--------------------
            overlayBuilderMap: {
              'Question': (BuildContext context, PlayerWithBG game) {
                return Center(
                  child: Container(
                    width: 100,
                    height: 100,
                    color: Colors.orange,
                    child: Center(child: Text('This is a question')),
                  ),
                );
              },
            },
            //-----------------------------------------------------------------
          ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in a few different ways:

**1.Use the overlays system**

Just like you tried, but to access the overlays you can use the fact that you have the `HasGameRef` mixin on your component, which gives your access to the `gameRef` variable and thus `gameRef.overlays.add/remove`.

You can read more about that [here](https://docs.flame-engine.org/1.5.0/flame/game.html#flutter-widgets-and-game-instances).

**2. Use the `RouterComponent`**

This technique is slightly more advanced, but it is definitely worth exploring if you will have a lot of different screens and scenes.

Example:

```dart
final router = RouterComponent(
  routes: {
    'ok-dialog': OverlayRoute(
      (context, game) {
        return Center(
          child: DecoratedContainer(...),
        );
      },
    ),  // OverlayRoute
    'confirm-dialog': OverlayRoute.existing(),
  },
);

router.pushNamed('ok-dialog);
```

You can read a lot more about that [here](https://docs.flame-engine.org/1.5.0/flame/router.html).

**3. Use the normal Flutter navigation**

The last, but least ergonomic way, is to use Flutter's built-in navigation (or another navigation package).
You can get the context in the same way as you accessed the `overlays`, when you have the `HasGameRef` mixin:

```dart
gameRef.buildContext;
```

Depending on how you do the navigation you might have to use the `GameWidget.controlled` constructor when you create your `GameWidget`.